# Disabling shuffle and sample in Array class

Tags: ruby

Let's suppose we want someone to write their own pseudorandom method. As programming exercise. And we want to raise an error each time they try to resolve to built-in functions as shortcut

So far, this is what I have done:

```
ERROR_STRING_FOR_RANDOM = "Usage of built-in random generators is not allowed"

methods_to_block = ["rand", "srand", "Random::rand", "Random::srand", 
"Random::seed", "Random::new", "Kernel::rand", "Kernel::srand",
"Array::shuffle", "Array::shuffle!", "Array::sample"]

methods_to_block.each do |method|
  eval 
  """
  def #{method}
  raise ERROR_STRING_FOR_RANDOM
  end
  """
end
```

So, it blocks Random, and these raise an error:

```
rand
srand
Random.new.rand(18)
```

but it doesn't work with pseudorandom methods of array. For example

```
[1,2,3].shuffle!
```

Still works. Why does that happen and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open up the class and replace the methods you want to disable...

```
class Array
  ERROR_STRING_FOR_RANDOM = "Usage of built-in random generators is not allowed"
  RANDOM_METHODS = [:shuffle, :shuffle!, :select]
  def rajarshi_random_error
    raise ERROR_STRING_FOR_RANDOM
  end
  RANDOM_METHODS.each do |m|
    define_method(m) {|*args| rajarshi_random_error }
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code was getting error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..4)
```

but for other like module functions you can just define the methods like

```
methods_to_block = ["rand", "srand","seed", "sample", "shuffle!", "shuffle!"]
```

it should be look like

```
 methods_to_block.each do |method|
   define_method "#{method}" do
     raise ERROR_STRING_FOR_RANDOM
   end
 end
 #=> ["rand", "srand", "Random::rand", "Random::srand", "Random::seed", "Random::new", "Kernel::rand", "Kernel::srand", "Array::shuffle", "Array::shuffle!", "Array::sample"]
```

Now if you call

```
> srand
RuntimeError: Usage of built-in random generators is not allowed

> rand
RuntimeError: Usage of built-in random generators is not allowed
```

hope it will help you

If you want to stick remain your way

```
ERROR_STRING_FOR_RANDOM = "Usage of built-in random generators is not allowed"

methods_to_block = ["rand", "srand", "Random::rand", "Random::srand", 
"Random::seed", "Random::new", "Kernel::rand", "Kernel::srand",
"Array::shuffle", "Array::shuffle!", "Array::sample"]


methods_to_block.each do |method|
if method.split("::").size > 1 && method.split("::").first != "Kernel"
class_name = method.split("::").first
method_name = method.split("::").last
er = <<ER
class #{class_name}
def #{method_name}
raise ERROR_STRING_FOR_RANDOM
end
end
ER
eval(er)
else
define_method "#{method}" do
raise ERROR_STRING_FOR_RANDOM
end
end
end
```

Now you can get all

```
> srand
RuntimeError: Usage of built-in random generators is not allowed

> rand
RuntimeError: Usage of built-in random generators is not allowed

> [2,3,4,5].shuffle
RuntimeError: Usage of built-in random generators is not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This works:

```
class Array
  undef_method :sample, :shuffle, :shuffle!
end
```

Using scope resolution operators was wrong idea to begin with. They just create constants inside classes instead of redefining methods

Similarly, proper way to disable rand and srand looks like this:

```
module Kernel
  undef_method :rand, :srand
  class << self
    undef_method :rand, :srand
  end
end

class Random
  undef_method :rand, :srand, :seed
  class << self
    undef_method :rand, :srand, :new
  end
end
```